# Elsevier cas-sc document class printing figures at the end of the document

Tags: floats, els-cas

I'm using the Elsevier `cas-sc` document class and it's printing Figures after the bibliography, at the end of the document. How to adjust it so that figures go before the bibliography?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{4modes_Energy_Consumption.eps}
\caption{Evaluation }
\label{4ModesEC}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{4modes_Electricity_bill_Payment.eps}
\caption{Evaluation of electricity}
\label{4ModesPay}
\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{DLC_DR}
Stenner, Karen, Elisha R. Frederiks, Elizabeth V. Hobman, and Stephanie Cook. "Willingness to participate in direct load control: The role of consumer distrust." Applied energy 189 (2017): 76-88.

\bibitem{Price_DR}
Takano, Hirotaka, Asuka Kudo, Hisao Taoka, and Atsumi Ohara. "A basic study on incentive pricing for demand response programs based on social welfare maximization." Journal of International Council on Electrical Engineering 8, no. 1 (2018): 136-144.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A hint: If you indent lines of code by four spaces\s, the site's software will pretty-print them automatically. While in edit mode, just highlight the lines you wish to pretty-print and click on the `{}` "box" in the ribbon above the editing window. (That's what I did right now to pretty-print your code.)

Comment: I don't have the two eps files mentioned in your code on my system. In order to make your code compilable, I have to add an option such as `demo` or `draft` to the list of document class options. Once I do that, the two `figure` environments are placed *before* the `thebibliography` environment. Isn't that exactly what you want? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

See documentation of  `endfloat` for more optional arguments. You can change the bibliography to your simple use of the environment `thebibliography`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers]{endfloat}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Test}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
            A & B \\
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{6cm}{5cm}
\caption{A caption for a figure}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

foo~\cite{aksin}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```